# Como identificar os repositórios existentes no meu github?

Tags: github

Estou fazendo um curso básico de github e só me passaram que o push tem que ser feito para "origin master".
 Porém quando faço o comando no terminal (linha de comando) recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> MacBook-Pro-de-Julio:Curso de Git juliobarreto$ git clonegit@github.com:juliocezarjr/curso-git.git github1 Cloning into
>   'github1'... ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Operation timed
>   out fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Obs: Não sei se tem alguma relação, mas pelo curso, era pra eu clonar o repositório usando uma SSH Key, só que não deu certo. Só consegui clonar o repositório pelo URL.

Comment: A propósito, creio que aqui você não se interessa pelo GitHub (serviço que provê hospedagem de projetos git + questões de redes sociais + talvez CI?), e sim o git propriamente dito. Saber os repositórios no GitHub é só abrir seu perfil, repositórios.

Comment: Meu problema acontece quando tento clonar um repositório do github. Então meu interesse no github é na medida em que não consigo clonar um repositório github.

Answer (score 1):

Execute o comando:

```
git remote -v
```

A relação são as URL's para onde é possível enviar o push. Deve existir pelo menos uma e por padrão é nomeada como Origin. Veja se a URL bate com a que está enviando o push.

Você também deve ter acesso ao repositório remoto, se está tentando fazer um push para um repo da sua conta do Github, o remote local deve apontar para a URL do repo no Github, aquela mesma que você usou para clonar.

Comment: O comando "git remote -v" não executa nada no meu terminal. Estou fazendo alguma coisa errada?

Comment: Você está na pasta do repositório? Se não tem nenhum retorno, é por que você não tem um remote cadastrado